# Retrieve elements of a CV_32FC3 CvMat?

Tags: c++, c, opencv

I'm creating a CvMat structure by calling

```
cvCreateMat(1,1,CV_32FC3);
```

This structure is filled by a subsequent OpenCV function call and fills it with three values (as far as I understand it, this is a 1x1 array with an additional depth of 3).

So how can I access these three values? A normal call to

```
CV_MAT_ELEM(myMat,float,0,0)
```

would not do the job since it expects only the arrays dimensions indices but not its depth. So how can I get these values?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The general way to access a cv::Mat is

```
type value=myMat.at<cv::VecNT>(j,i)[channel]
```

For your case:

```
Mat mymat(1,1,CV_32FC3,cvScalar(0.1,0.2,0.3));
float val=mymat.at<Vec3f>(0,0)[0];
```

All of the types are defined using the class cv::VecNT where T is the type and N is the number of vector elements.

Answer (score 5):

`CV_32FC3` is a three channel matrix of 32-bit floats. You can access each channel by declaring a struct element with 3 floats and using `CV_MAT_ELEM`. For example:

```
typedef struct element {
        float cn1;
        float cn2;
        float cn3;
} myElement;

myElement data[N] = ...;
CvMat mat = cvMat(1, 1, CV_32FC2, data);

float channel1 = CV_MAT_ELEM(mat, float, 0, 0).cn1;
float channel2 = CV_MAT_ELEM(mat, float, 0, 0).cn2;
float channel3 = CV_MAT_ELEM(mat, float, 0, 0).cn3;
```

Edit:

Another way to access each channel is by using the underlying `ptr` structure:

```
mat.ptr<float>(x, y) [channel];
```

Comment: OK, that does not exactly solve myp roblem. Here the part where I fill data[N] is missing, this is done by the OpenCV function I call. So myMat is created as CV_32FC3, then OpenCV fills it with data and then I want to access these data. Means I don't know where/how to assign that structure to myMap in order to access the channels...

Comment: @Elmi: See my edited post. You can use the `ptr` member as well.